# Is it possible use web audio API with vimeo iframe

Tags: vimeo, web-audio-api

I'm trying to extract or just analyze the audio from a vimeo video with the web audio API and was wondering if it's possible and how.

Right now I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLMediaElement'
```

… when I try a createMediaElementSource(video) where video is my iframe

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think it is not possible to do what you want. At least not exactly in the way you want it.

The `createMediaElementSource()` factory function only works with media elements. And those are only `<audio/>` and `<video/>` elements. This is why it doesn't work when you use it with the `<iframe/>` directly.

Normally you would query such a media element for example by its id like this:

```
document.querySelector('#myAudioElement');
```

But this is not that easy if the element is inside an `<iframe/>`. Then it is only possible to query an element if the `<iframe/>` and the parent document do have the same origin. This is because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) which is a security feature. Imagine what an attacker could do if it was possible to load any page in an `<iframe/>` and then modify it at will.

Of course it is a hindrance for your use case. Maybe building a browser extension is an option for you because they have usually more privileges and can query the DOM of any page the browser loads.

Alternatively it is also possible to disable the same-origin policy in some browsers. But that is usually only useful during development because you can only disable this policy for the whole browser which is a security problem unless you only open sites that you fully trust.